# Телеграмм бот не видит текста в сообщении с фото

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```html
import configparser, telebot


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

bot_token = config['Telegram']['bot_token']
channel_id = config['Channel']['channel_id']

bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет ✌️ ")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'text'])
def get_news(message):
    print(message.chat)
    print()
    print(message.text)
    print()
    print(message.photo)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Есть код бота, который должен принимать от пользователя сообщение с текстом и фото, но если в сообщении есть фото, он не видит текста

Ответ программы:

```
{'id': '-', 'type': 'private', 'title': None, 'username': '-', 'first_name': '-', 'last_name': None, 'photo': None, 'bio': None, 'join_to_send_messages': None, 'join_by_request': None, 'has_private_forwards': None, 'description': None, 'invite_link': None, 'pinned_message': None, 'permissions': None, 'slow_mode_delay': None, 'message_auto_delete_time': None, 'has_protected_content': None, 'sticker_set_name': None, 'can_set_sticker_set': None, 'linked_chat_id': None, 'location': None}

None

[<telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x000001A815B6FCC0>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x000001A815B6F048>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x000001A815B6FAC8>, <telebot.types.PhotoSize object at 0x000001A815B6FB00>]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы имеете ввиду подпись к фото?

```
print(message.caption)
```